# maven-assembly-plugin: use config.properties during development and but pack config.default.properties as config.properties on jar-with-dependencies

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, maven-assembly-plugin, exclude-constraint

I've got two configuration files (with usernames and passwords for the database for the testing phase) in `src\main\resources\{config.properties,config.default.properties}` During the development  and my own testing I would like use `src\main\resources\config.properties`. On packaging the project, I'd like to include `src\main\resources\config.default.properties` as `config.properties` in the single jar with dependencies. How can I tell this directly in the single `pom.xml`? I tried to exclude `src\main\resources\config.properties` with this section, but even that didn't work:

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>

            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.great.tech.Client</mainClass>
                        <packageName>com.great.tech.client</packageName>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    </manifest>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Created-By>Great Technologies AG</Created-By>
                        <Version>${project.version}</Version>
                        <Title>Great Tech</Title>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>

                <dependencySets>
                    <dependencySet>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>**/config.properties</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </dependencySet>
                </dependencySets>
            </configuration>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>

        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define profile for environments

```
     <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <properties>
            <activatedProperties>dev</activatedProperties>
        </properties>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <properties>
            <activatedProperties>prod</activatedProperties>
        </properties>
    </profile>
```

Then you can specify the property to be used in maven command like `mvn install -Pdev` this will refer dev properties file.

Then add your properties files to `profiles/dev/config.properties` and `profiles/prod/config.properties` in the project so that `-Pdev` can refer to the file. Finally add a plugin to copy the appropriate file to the resources:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.coderplus.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>copy-rename-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-file</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceFile>profiles/${build.profile.id}/config.properties</sourceFile>
                            <destinationFile>src/main/resources/config.properties</destinationFile>
                        </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```